# Microsoft Teams: Is at all possible to create a app/connector/bot for broadcasting?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Trying to parse through the Microsoft Documentation of this is a bit of a challenge.

Our use case is that we want the app to receive broadcasts from an external service.  On that broadcast we want it to send a personalized message to every person in the team/org.

Is that at all possible?  Doing this in Workplace and Slack was fairly straight forward but i'm going nowhere fast with Teams.  Connectors seem weird and user-based, not team based, requiring you to set up a config page for it?  Bots seem centered around AI interactions and on demand features and general apps?  Not sure.

So yea the question is,  is it possible.  If so i would appreciate to know where to look for how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible. If you're wanting to send to a Team (i.e. a Channel within a Team) you can use either a bot or a webhook. If you want to send to individuals or to group chats, then you'd be looking to use a bot.

For webhooks, see [Post external requests to Teams with incoming webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook). For bots you can start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/what-are-bots), and in that case you'd want to look into something called ["Pro-active messaging"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-proactive-messaging), where the bot is sending a message on it's own, rather in response to a user's initial message.

The Pro-active messaging can be a bit tricky, so if you do want to go that approach (1 to 1 messaging), let me know in the comments and I give you some more guidance. However, I'd suggest rather looking at messaging the Team, and creating/using a relevant channel, rather than sending every user a 1-1 message.

Comment: Oh wow thank you so much.   It really sound have been nice if the pro-active part was in the actual 'making a bot' documentation.

Is there some technical limitiation to sending many 1-1 messages?  Is there no batch messaging in the api?   The thing is that each person needs to get an individual link sent to them with a token assigned to them.

Comment: ah ok, with unique tokens that makes sense. There are throttling limits, but it's nicely covered at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/rate-limit

Comment: Thank you Hilton,  you might be saving me from madness.  I've made graph api connections to multiple systems and NEVER been this stuck before.  I got completely stuck on looking into connectors and was so damn confused.