# BotFramework v4: Programmatically push messages to specific channels/individual users/groups

Tags: .net, .net-core, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I was reading the documentation of ,NET BotFramework v4 but for some reasons I can't figure out a way to implement that.

I would like to create a ASP .NET Core Web Service that takes a message in input, that builds a Teams-compliant message and push it to Teams. This message can be pushed to a specific channel, to multiple channels or privately to individual users (based on some routing rules that I have to define).

My question is: how can I scan all Teams channels/users/group in my organisation and route the message accordingly?

Can I use the .NET BotFramework or should I use REST API?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, the question isn't *really* all that clear - I don't understand why you need to scan all "Teams/users/groups", and what you'd be looking for? At any rate, you can get most of what you're looking for from the Microsoft Graph, but be aware that some things can be accessed using "Application" authentication (e.g. Teams/Channel) but some things would require Delegated access (e.g. users/group chats), so it would be tricky to scan "everything", so to speak.

With regards to sending messages to channels, group chats, and 1-1 conversations (e.g. with a bot), see this answer I posted recently, which should head you in the right direction: [Microsoft Teams: Is at all possible to create a app/connector/bot for broadcasting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60853248/microsoft-teams-is-at-all-possible-to-create-a-app-connector-bot-for-broadcasti)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry if the question is not clear, I will try to explain myself better. We'd like to create a service that keeps track of all users/channels in the organisation. This service takes a message in input and after routing it (based on an internal routing layer that we'll provide) it will push the message to the right user/channel. I have never used Microsoft Graph, maybe it's the perfect solution to get the references to the channels/users on Teams so that we can target them with messages/adaptive cards/etc...?

Comment: Yes, as I said, it can do what you need, but you need to understand that some of the endpoints on the graph can be accessed with a global type of permission, called "Application" in the docs, and some will require the user to specifically approve/allow the app to access data on their behalf (called "Delegated" in the docs). This is because of what you're trying to do - access both general Teams stuff, but also access "personal" use things like private 1-1 conversations

Comment: I will try it and report back here. I have just noticed that the Microsoft Graph beta version allows to POST stuff onto channels. I will give it a go. It sounds brilliant to me. Thanks! (When I am reaching 15 of reputation I will upvote you!)

Comment: great stuff, give it a go and let me know. I think you should be able to "mark as answer", even if you can't upvote?