# How to send simple message to Microsoft Teams channel using csharp?

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams

I can't find anything to send simple message to MS Teams channels, I'm using Csharp and don't need reply to messages.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using C#, one way to send messages to teams channel is using webhook url. Below code will help sending message to teams.

```
string webhookUrl = "<enter Teams webhook url>";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(webhookUrl);
Message body = new Message();
body.text = "Hello World";
string serializeJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);
StringContent content = new StringContent(serializeJson,Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
_ = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, content);
```

Declare a Message class

```
public class Message
{
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

Webhook url can be set up by creating an `Incoming webhook` connection on desired Teams channel:
[image]

Comment: Nicely done. I was having issues with doing it via Graph API and for now this solution works just fine.

Comment: How to post HTML formatted message?

Answer (score 2):

You can send messages to Teams channel using webhook. You can post messages by setting up incoming webhook within channel. Please look at [Post external request in Teams with incoming webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook). But you should specify your requirement you can achieve this with the Bot. A bot is also helpful to have conversation within Teams channel. Bot supported `[Personal, Team, GroupChat]` scope. Please go through the [Conversation basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/conversation-basics?tabs=dotnet#send-a-message) for more information how bot works within different scopes.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to accomplish this, depending on what your other broader requirements might be. Options are, for instance, webhooks or a bot, but please see my answer at [Microsoft Teams: Is at all possible to create a app/connector/bot for broadcasting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60853248/microsoft-teams-is-at-all-possible-to-create-a-app-connector-bot-for-broadcasti/60855270#60855270)

Answer (score 1):

To add to the above, [MessageCardModel](https://github.com/poychang/MessageCardModel) on Github/NuGet has a model for sending adaptive cards to MS Teams

There's a playground at [MessageCardPlayground](https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/) which shows how the card formats when rendered in teams.

Simple creating a model like this and serializing to Json and posting to a WebHook channel results in some nice output.

```
// Create a variable like below
var card = new MessageCard
{
    Title = "This is the title",
    Text = "Message text",
    Sections = new[]
    {
        new Section
        {
            Text = "Section title",
            Actions = new[]
            {
                new OpenUriAction
                {
                    Name = "Open My Blog",
                    Type = ActionType.OpenUri,
                    Targets = new List<Target>
                    {
                        new Target
                        {
                            OS = TargetOs.Default,
                            Uri = "http://blog.poychang.net/"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
// Now you get Json string to send or play in https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net
var json = card.ToJson();
```

Full example of usage at this repo [Logging.MSTeams](https://github.com/poychang/Logging.MSTeams/tree/master/Logging.MSTeams)